# include and include_once not working properly in Localhost wamp

Tags: php

I have a problem with working project.
when I download project and run it my localhost(wamp server) many error occurred.

I have a `config.php` file include website configurations like database settings.
when I use `include('inc/config.php')` in other files this error happen

> Notice: Constant DOC_ROOT already defined in
>   C:\wamp64\www\sahartest\inc\config.php on line 3

and when I use `include_once`, variables located in `config.php` not recognized

> Notice: Undefined variable: globalConfig in
>   C:\wamp64\www\sahartest\inc\protect.class.php on line 21

**Config.php:**

```
<?php
define('DOC_ROOT', '/sahartest/');
$globalConfig['dbhost']="localhost"; // Your MySQL Server Host URL
$globalConfig['dbuser']="root"; // Your MySQL Username
$globalConfig['dbpass']=""; // Your MySQL Password
$globalConfig['dbase']="saharsms"; // Your MySQL Database name
```

**This project work in Server and problem is in the localhost**

Any Idea?

Comment: either file-path provided to include is incorrect or file included two times.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh  I also used `$_server['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`; nothing happened.

Comment: What is the code in protect.class.php?

Comment: @miknik I just include `config.php` file